# Pandas .rolling.corr using date/time offset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am having a bit of an issue with pandas's rolling function and I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong. If I mock up two test series of numbers:

```
df_index = pd.date_range(start='1990-01-01', end ='2010-01-01', freq='D')
test_df = pd.DataFrame(index=df_index)

test_df['Series1'] = np.random.randn(len(df_index))
test_df['Series2'] = np.random.randn(len(df_index))
```

Then it's easy to have a look at their rolling annual correlation:

```
test_df['Series1'].rolling(365).corr(test_df['Series2']).plot()
```

which produces:

[image]

All good so far. If I then try to do the same thing using a datetime offset:

```
test_df['Series1'].rolling('365D').corr(test_df['Series2']).plot()
```

I get a wildly different (and obviously wrong) result:

[image]

Is there something wrong with pandas or is there something wrong with me?

Thanks in advance for any light you can shed on this troubling conundrum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very tricky, I think the behavior of `window` as *`int`* and *`offset`* is different:

> New in version 0.19.0 are the ability to pass an offset (or
>     convertible) to a .rolling() method and have it produce variable sized
>     windows based on the passed time window. **For each time point, this
>     includes all preceding values occurring within the indicated time
>     delta.**
>
> This can be particularly **useful for a non-regular time frequency index**.

You should checkout the doc of [Time-aware Rolling](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#time-aware-rolling).

```
r1 = test_df['Series1'].rolling(window=365) # has default `min_periods=365`
r2 = test_df['Series1'].rolling(window='365D') # has default `min_periods=1`
r3 = test_df['Series1'].rolling(window=365, min_periods=1)

r1.corr(test_df['Series2']).plot()
r2.corr(test_df['Series2']).plot()
r3.corr(test_df['Series2']).plot()
```

This code would produce similar shape of plots for `r2.corr().plot()` and `r3.corr().plot()`, but note that the calculation results still different: `r2.corr(test_df['Series2']) == r3.corr(test_df['Series2'])`.

I think for regular time frequency index, you should just stick to `r1`.

Comment: Like you say, it does seem to be different, but I can't see a reason in the 'Time-aware Rolling' doc that it should be. It seems like an error with pandas. And yes I guess the solution for the time being is just to not use the time offset feature.

Answer (score 1):

This mainly because the result of two rolling 365 and 365D are different.
For example

```
sub = test_df.head()
sub['Series2'].rolling(2).sum()
Out[15]: 
1990-01-01         NaN
1990-01-02   -0.355230
1990-01-03    0.844281
1990-01-04    2.515529
1990-01-05    1.508412

sub['Series2'].rolling('2D').sum()
Out[16]: 
1990-01-01   -0.043692
1990-01-02   -0.355230
1990-01-03    0.844281
1990-01-04    2.515529
1990-01-05    1.508412
```

Since there are a lot NaN in rolling 365, so the corr of two series in two way are quit different.